# Ruby on Rails - Loop Erroring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, nginx, while-loop

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 with nginx and i have a form that loops to add a new record. Everything works. EXCEPT for the looping. If set for more then 14 it errors at loop 4 @ field 5 (equipment) and stops...

If you set 14 or less works perfectly...

I think it might be a limit in NginX

```
.row-fluid
    .span12
        - i = 1
        = form_tag do
            %table.many_trucks
                %thead
                    %tr
                        %th
                        %th
                            Origin
                        %th
                            Destination
                        %th
                            Available
                        %th
                            Expiration
                        %th
                            Equipment
                        %th
                            Comments
                %tbody
                    - while i <= params[:truck_count].to_f
                        %tr{ :id => "#{i}" }
                            %td= i.to_s+"."
                                = hidden_field_tag "trucks[#{i}][user_id]", current_user.id.to_s
                            %td
                                = autocomplete_field_tag "trucks[#{i}][origin]", '', autocomplete_location_cs_loads_path, {:class => "input-small",:placeholder=>ADDRESSHOLDER}
                            %td
                                = autocomplete_field_tag "trucks[#{i}][dest]", '', autocomplete_location_cs_loads_path, {:class => "input-small", :placeholder=>ADDRESSHOLDER}
                            %td
                                = text_field_tag "trucks[#{i}][available]", '', {:class => "input-small datepicker", :placeholder=>DATEHOLDER}
                            %td
                                = text_field_tag "trucks[#{i}][expiration]", '', {:class => "input-small datepicker", :placeholder=>DATEHOLDER}
                            %td
                                = select_tag "trucks[#{i}][equipment_id]", options_for_select(Equipment.all.map{|equipment| [equipment.name, equipment.id]}), {:class => "input-medium"}
                            %td
                                = text_field_tag "trucks[#{i}][comments]"
                    -i +=1
            %hr
            =submit_tag "Post", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Can you strip off the excessive code so it's more clear for everyone who will attempt to review your code. Leave only the erroneous loop instead of pasting the entire file.

Comment: Also why are you converting `params[:truck_count]` to `float` when comparing it with an `int` in the loop?

Comment: Also please post the error that is thrown.

Comment: Why don't you consider saving this `options_for_select(Equipment.all.map{|equipment| [equipment.name, equipment.id]})` to a variable. Then just add the variable as an argument to the `select_tag`. What your code does is (if sql caching is disabled) for each loop it queries the database to get all equipment available.

Comment: good points... will modify that..  I pasted the entire file because I Hate HAML because i was stuck on an issue for 2 weeks before i figured out all that need done was to indent the form...

Comment: P.S. Wouldn't it also make sense for `i` to start from `0` instead of `1`? IDK what your code is supposed to do, so it's just a suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the indent of this line:

```
-i +=1
```

It's on the same level as the while loop. So technically you are doing:

```
while i <= params[:truck_count].to_i do # !! This is what you want to do (to_i)
  ...
end
i += 1
```

It's an infinite loop depending on `params[:truck_count].to_f`.
Also I suspect that querying the database every time within the loop (as described in one of my comments):

```
Equipment.all.map{|equipment| [equipment.name, equipment.id]}
```

causes the error. Probably a timeout or sth.

Hope it helps.